# Get enemy attack to the fps controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;     // The time in seconds  between each attack.
    public int attackDamage = 10;               // The amount of health taken away per attack.

    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator component.
    GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;                  // Reference to the player's health.
    //EnemyHealth enemyHealth;                    // Reference to this enemy's health.
    bool playerInRange;                         // Whether player is within the trigger collider and can be attacked.
float timer;                                // Timer for counting up to the next attack.

void Awake ()
{
    // Setting up the references.
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
    //enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
    anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
}

public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    // If the entering collider is the player...
    if(other.gameObject == player)
    {
        // ... the player is in range.
        playerInRange = true;
        anim = ("idle0ToAttack1");
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{
    // If the exiting collider is the player...
    if(other.gameObject == player)
    {
        // ... the player is no longer in range.
        playerInRange = false;
    }
}


void Update ()
{
    // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    // If the timer exceeds the time between attacks, the player is in range                 and this enemy is alive...
    if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange /*&& enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0*/)
    {
        // ... attack.
        Attack ();
    }

    // If the player has zero or less health...
    if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        // ... tell the animator the player is dead.
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}


void Attack ()
{
    // Reset the timer.
    timer = 0f;

    // If the player has health to lose...
    if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        // ... damage the player.
        playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
     }
    }
 }
```

I want to get the enemy attack to the fps player. How do I do that? At the same time I want my fps controller to die. For your help I've also written the comments so that you all can understand.

Comment: It appears a substantial piece of assistance was rendered below, Durvesh, but it completely slipped your mind to respond in some fashion. To respond to a post, you can comment, upvote or accept. If you do not do any of these things, a helper can become demoralised and decide that helping people is a waste of their time. So, will you respond to them now?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want your enemy to **Path Find** the player.

*Read this if you need more help:* [Unity Topics: Navigation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation)

First step, all objects that you want for your enemy to **walk on** must be selected as "*static*". (Click on the GameObject and tick 'static' in the top right corner)

Now you need to go to *Windows>Navigation* and click "Bake" down the bottom once you like your settings.

Make sure your "Enemy" has a **rigid body** on them and then add **"Nav Mesh Agent"** component.

Now add (or edit) a script on the enemy and add the code (make sure to add this up the top `using UnityEngine.AI;`):

```
//NavMeshAgent
private NavMeshAgent agent;

//Target Transform
public Transform trans;

void Start()
{
    //Get the component
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

}

private void Update()
{
    SetDestination(trans.position);
}

void SetDestination (Vector3 des)
{
    //Set the destination
    agent.SetDestination(des);
}
```

And there you go, there are other methods of doing this but this is by far the simplest.

EDIT:

This is what your script should look like:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;     // The time in seconds  between each attack.
    public int attackDamage = 10;               // The amount of health taken away per attack.

    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator component.
    GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;                  // Reference to the player's health.
    //EnemyHealth enemyHealth;                    // Reference to this enemy's health.
    bool playerInRange;                         // Whether player is within the trigger collider and can be attacked.
    float timer;                                // Timer for counting up to the next attack.

    //NavMeshAgent
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    //Target Transform
    public Transform trans;

    void Start()
    {
        //Get the component
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    }
    void SetDestination(Vector3 des)
    {
        //Set the destination
        agent.SetDestination(des);
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        //enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // If the entering collider is the player...
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is in range.
            playerInRange = true;
            anim = ("idle0ToAttack1");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        // If the exiting collider is the player...
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is no longer in range.
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }


    void Update()
    {
        SetDestination(trans.position);

        // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        // If the timer exceeds the time between attacks, the player is in range                 and this enemy is alive...
        if (timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange /*&& enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0*/)
        {
            // ... attack.
            Attack();
        }

        // If the player has zero or less health...
        if (playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // ... tell the animator the player is dead.
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }


    void Attack()
    {
        // Reset the timer.
        timer = 0f;

        // If the player has health to lose...


  if (playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        // ... damage the player.
        playerHealth.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    }
}
}
```